# How to Reflection on EntityFramework Classes (model first approach)?

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-4.1

It's possible to create instance of classes generated for VisualStudio when use DataBase First ?

I mean, I use the t4 templates and the command "Generate Code" using T4 templates for MVC3 Tools Update to create my classes from db with a many to many relationship.

Can I Use reflection to "populate" the properties of an instance for example of "Student" of this classes in a distinct assembly (dll) ?

For example with 3 tables:
"courses"
"students"
"studentsCourses"

I will have 3 entities, on for courses, one for students and one for the relationship.
Can I receive an object or type "student" and use reflection to "populate" all it's properties ? and If yes, how can I achieve this ?

I already know I can receive the object by reference as "object type" (using generics) but I just can't figure out how to create/fill the complex properties (for example in the studentsCourses property)

Any advice thanks in advance.

Here I let the script to create the tables and the database "COURSES_TEST":

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [COURSES_TEST]    Script Date: 04/12/2013 23:47:18 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'COURSES_TEST', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\COURSES_TEST.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'COURSES_TEST_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\COURSES_TEST_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [COURSES_TEST].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET ARITHABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET  DISABLE_BROKER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET  READ_WRITE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET  MULTI_USER
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM
GO
ALTER DATABASE [COURSES_TEST] SET DB_CHAINING OFF
GO
USE [COURSES_TEST]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[students]    Script Date: 04/12/2013 23:47:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[students](
    [studentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [lastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [studentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[courses]    Script Date: 04/12/2013 23:47:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[courses](
    [courseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [course] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_courses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [courseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Studentscourses]    Script Date: 04/12/2013 23:47:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Studentscourses](
    [courseStudentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [courseID] [int] NULL,
    [studentID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Studentscourses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [courseStudentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_Studentscourses_courses]    Script Date: 04/12/2013 23:47:19 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Studentscourses]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Studentscourses_courses] FOREIGN KEY([courseID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[courses] ([courseID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Studentscourses] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Studentscourses_courses]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_Studentscourses_students]    Script Date: 04/12/2013 23:47:19 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Studentscourses]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Studentscourses_students] FOREIGN KEY([studentID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[students] ([studentID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Studentscourses] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Studentscourses_students]
GO
```

Comment: Why would you want to use reflection? That's hardly ever necessary in normal production code. Maybe in framework-like components. What's the bigger picture?

Comment: Indeed, I don't agree with use reflection, but I was asked to do it.

The bigger picture, it's that some websites already running send me the object (it has the same base estructure) and I have to "fill it" with the certain information, but they don't want to modify the projects to make reference to my DLL, instead they just want modify the line where the object is built it, for a call to a method on my DLL to send the object. (I don't really get it at all, I'm not an architect, but with my few experiencie I can't feel that reflection is not the right way).

Comment: Can't you agree on exchanging a list of key-value pairs like `{property1, "value1"},{property2, "2"},{property3, "2013/4/13"},...`

Comment: The problem are the nav properties (the ones that are caused because of relationships on db), and that I was working with 2 assemblies in the "real" solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, EF generates something like

> ```
> class YourStudent
> {
>     public int studentId { get; set; }
>     public string name { get; set; }
>     public string lastName { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
> }
> ```

and there is

```
class TheirStudent
{
    public int studentId {get;set;}
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

and you want to stuff values from a TheirStudent instance into a YourStudent instance.

Maybe something like

```
YourStudent s1;
TheirStudent s2;
Type t = typeof(YourStudent);
Type t2 = typeof(TheirStudent);

foreach (PropertyInfo pinfo in t.GetProperties()) 
{
    if (pinfo.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual &&
        pinfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
        pinfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
    {

        // This is [probably] a nav property. Courses would be in here
    }
    else if (pinfo.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual)
    {
        // if you have 0..1 or 1..1 nav properties you might muck around in here
    }
    else if (!pinfo.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual)
    {
        // This is [probably] a column - studentId, name, etc would be here

        // you could pull values over like so:
        PropertyInfo pinfo2 = (from ps in t2.GetProperties() 
                               where ps.Name == pinfo.Name 
                               select ps).SingleOrDefault();
        if (pinfo2 != null)
        {
            object value = pinfo2.GetValue(s2, new object[] { });
            pinfo.SetValue(s1, value, new object[] { });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do something like you mention, but my problem are the nav properties, it seems to work in a recursive way or something, when you watch them, you can expand and expand until the end of times, how could I to create that nav properties ? is possible ?